# Creating a tag list with links from comma separated list

Tags: php

I am storing a list of tags in a comma separated list in my database.

An example of this data is:

```
Graphic Design, Illustration, Animation
```

I am outputting the comma separated list and creating the links with the following:

```
$Tags = explode(', ', $value['Tags']);
foreach($Tags as $key => $value) {
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . 'news/tag/' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
}
```

When you click on a link it uses the query

```
WHERE Tags LIKE "%' . $tag . '%"
```

This only seems to work if I click on the second, third, fourth, etc. link but not the first one.

I am assuming it has something to do with the comma or white space.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($Tags)`? Also, the convention is to write variable names with small letters.

Comment: @Stephen : At first time, the `$Tag` value is goes with actual value right?

Comment: try with `"%' . urldecode($tag) . '%"`, might be the first tag comes like `Graphic+Design` in url!

Comment: @jurgemaister I get "Graphic Design, Illustration, Animation"

Comment: @jogesh_pi unfortunately not. Have tested that as well by moving the order of the tags and it is always the first one that fails.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the generated query? then try to run it against your db using phpMyAdmin or something equivalent and see if the generated query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to explode on command AND space. Explode on comma only and trim space later.

Try this:

```
$Tags = explode(',', 'Graphic Design, Illustration, Animation');

foreach ($Tags as $tag) {
    $tag = trim($tag);
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . 'news/tag/' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a><br>';
}
```

Then on your query, do the following:

```
WHERE Tags LIKE "%' . urldecode(trim($tag)) . '%"
```

Outputs:

```
<a href="BASE_URLnews/tag/Graphic Design">Graphic Design</a><br>
<a href="BASE_URLnews/tag/Illustration">Illustration</a><br>
<a href="BASE_URLnews/tag/Animation">Animation</a><br>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Output is correct but the first link still doesn't work.

Comment: When you click the link, you are generating that query. Can you var_dump it and show us how the query is being generated? Have a look at what `jogesh_pi` said, that might be the issue.

Comment: @lathessan ok now the problem is obvious. I am getting WHERE Tags LIKE "% Graphic Design%" So if I add a space in front of Graphic Design in the DB the query works as expected. Not sure how the white space is being added in.

Comment: i've updated my answer, try that. You have to trim the `$tag` in your query.

Comment: All working now. When the tag was passed to my controller a space was being added in front of it before it was passed to the model. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first tag "Graphic Design" has a space which is unsafe in urls. Remove it, replace it or use `urlencode()`:

```
$Tags = explode(', ', $value['Tags']);
foreach($Tags as $key => $value) {
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . 'news/tag/' . urlencode($value) . '">' . $value . '</a>';
}
```